# How to display element at the left screen side depends on mobile screen resolution using css?

Tags: css

I prepared simple example it's similar to situation i have, you can check example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/OopsUserName/hmtds81q/)
How can i make display green block on full screen width, i'm not allowed to change parent classes,
if i do `margin-left: -20px` it works but not fully i have empty area if i scale it and i depends on screen resolution, perhaps parents classes in hierarchy have margins too, i tired to use `!important` it didn't work too, tried to use `width: 1wv` - the same result, I would like to know how can i display element since left side and ignore parents class settings ?

Comment: Does this is what you want?? https://jsfiddle.net/kLr01za4/

Comment: Your question is quite misleading and confusing. Please tell us properly what is your actual problem? On which resolution what should be output? Also your actual code..... As there are plenty of ways doing it, but without knowing your actual styles we can't answer it properly

Comment: One of way mentioned by Maniraj

Comment: @Kenny absolutely agree with you, it's because of i'm not familiar with css, sorry for made a mess in my question, it's deffucult to explain without full undeestanding what's going on, thanks for your coment